# What plug-in is StackOverflow using for their modal dialogs?

Tags: discussion

Looking for a really good jQuery modal dialog plugin. I really like the one used here, so was just wondering what it was.

Comment: View --> Page Source  ;-D

Comment: @Lee - Can you describe or screenshot the dialog you are talking about?  The answer I give is for the notifications that appear at the top of the screen, but you might be talking about some other dialog...

Comment: Yes, should have elaborated -- I meant the little popup modals that appear when you, for example, try to execute an unallowed action or what not.

Thanks for the link out to SO in your original answer, some interesting insights there.

Pollyanna

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code that causes the notification to appear:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var msgArray = [{"id":1393859,"messageTypeId":2,"text":"You have 1 new comment. See your \u003ca href=\"/users/recent/2915/2010-02-23/2010-02-24?tab=responses\"\u003eresponses\u003c/a\u003e.","userId":2915,"showProfile":false}];
        $(function() { notify.showMessages(msgArray); });
    </script>
```

And here are the scripts executed/loaded immediately prior to the above code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://sstatic.net/so/js/master.js?v=6180"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">var imagePath = 'http://sstatic.net/so/img/';</script>
```

You'll have to do a little more digging, but perhaps this will get you started.

Alternately, [find another similar solution on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770038/best-ways-to-display-notifications-with-jquery/770057#770057).

The notify function simply inserts an html table.  It's located in the master.js script:

```
var notify = function() {
   var d = false;
   var e = 0;
   var c =- 1;
   var g = "m";
   var a = function(i) {
      if(!d) {
         $("#notify-container").append('<table id="notify-table"></table>');
         d = true}
      var h = "<tr" + (i.messageTypeId ? ' id="notify-' + i.messageTypeId + '"':"");
      h += ' class="notify" style="display:none"><td class="notify">' + i.text;
      if(i.showProfile) {
         var j = escape("/users/" + i.userId);
         h += ' See your <a href="/messages/mark-as-read?messagetypeid=' + i.messageTypeId + "&returnurl=" + escape(j) + '">profile</a>.'}
      h += '</td><td class="notify-close"><a title="dismiss this notification" onclick="notify.close(';
      h += (i.messageTypeId ? i.messageTypeId : "") + ')">&times;</a></td></tr>';
      $("#notify-table").append(h)};
   var b = function(h) {
      $.cookie(g, (h ? h : "0"), {
         expires : 90, path : "/"}
      )};
   var f = function() {
      var h = parseInt($.cookie(g));
      if(isNaN(h)) {
         h = 0}
      if(h < 5) {
         $(".module.newuser").show();
         b(++h)}
      };
   return {
      showFirstTime : function() {
         if($.cookie(g)) {
            f()}
         else {
            $(".module.newuser").show();
            $("body").css("margin-top", "2.5em");
            a( {
               messageTypeId : c, text : 'First time here? Check out the <a onclick="notify.closeFirstTime()">FAQ</a>!'}
            );
            $(".notify").fadeIn("slow")}
         }
      , showMessages : function(h) {
         for(var j = 0; j < h.length; j++) {
            a(h[j])}
         $(".notify").fadeIn("slow");
         e = h.length}
      , show : function(h) {
         $("body").css("margin-top", "2.5em");
         a( {
            text : h}
         );
         $(".notify").fadeIn("slow")}
      , close : function(h) {
         var j;
         var i = 0;
         if(h && h != c) {
            $.post("/messages/mark-as-read", {
               messagetypeid : h}
            );
            j = $("#notify-" + h);
            if(e > 1) {
               i = parseInt($("body").css("margin-top").match(/\d+/));
               i = i - (i / e)}
            }
         else {
            if(h && h == c) {
               b()}
            j = $(".notify")}
         j.children("td").css("border-bottom", "none").end().fadeOut("fast", function() {
            $("body").css("margin-top", i + "px"); j.remove()}
         )}
      , closeFirstTime : function() {
         b();
         document.location = "/faq"}
      }
   }
```

Comment: SO's JS code is compressed and this makes it obfuscated too. It's orders of magnitude faster to write the code yourself (even counting the time overhead of having to learn how to do it if you don't already) than to try and reverse engineer it.

Comment: @Koper - I dunno.  The code looks readable enough to me.  If I wanted to spend time on it, I think it *might* be worthwhile removing the SO specific stuff and renaming variables so it all makes more sense - cut it down to a bare minimum example.  But yes, as it is, it isn't trivial to understand.

Comment: I took the question to mean the modal window that appears when you vote to close a question, not the notification bar at the top of the page.

Comment: @John - Ah, well if that's the case then the above code is of little use.  I guess we'll have to wait for the OP to respond for clarification...